Prove that a set of homomorphism is Noetherian
I am currently working on the following questions ($M$ is a finite $A$-module and $N$ a Noetherian $A$-module):

Prove that for all $l$ in $N$, A-module $N^l$ is Noetherian (this part was ok I proved it by recurrence using the properties of exact sequences)
Deduce from 1) that the set of $A$-modules homomorphism from $M$ to $N$ is a Noetherian A-module

I am really struggling to see how 2 can be deduced from 1.
I just started studying modules theory, so I don't have a strong understanding of the concepts involved yet.
Thanks in advance for your help

Please use MathJax when you post here. A tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Hint: Assume that $M$ is finitely generated by $a_1,...,a_l$. Define a map $\theta:\text{Hom}_A(M,N)\to N^l$ by $\theta(\varphi)=(\varphi(a_1),...,\varphi(a_l))$. What can you say about $\theta$?

It's bijective so Hom(,) and ^ are isomorphic. As a result Hom(,) is Noetherien A-module ?

@Idoia It's not necessary surjective, because we don't know that $M$ is a free module. However, it is definitely injective, and so $\text{Hom}_A(M,N)$ is isomorphic to a submodule of $N^l$.

Thank you so much. It is now very clear for me.

@Idoia If the answer was helpful, please consider accepting it. This will in particular remove the question from the unanswered questions list.

Just did it, sorry I am not completely familiar with the forum. Thanks again
